# VC++ Generic Singleton Implementation Compiler Error

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, generics, singleton

So, let's say I have something like this:

```
template <class T>
class SingletonHolder : public T
{
public:
    static SingletonHolder<T>& getInstance()
    {

        static SingletonHolder<T> instance;
        return instance;
    }



private:
    SingletonHolder()
    {
    }


    virtual ~SingletonHolder()
    {
    }


};//class SingletonHolder
```

and say I have some dummy class:

```
class SomeClassForCheck
{
public:
    int someF()
    {
        return 5;
    }
};
```

And then the usage of singleton:

```
typedef SingletonHolder< SomeClassForCheck > SomeClassSingleton;
```

And then when I call this code from   SomeClasse's  CPP file  (outside of any function) :
[Idea behind is to basically use this trick to register a creator function to a Singleton Factory Class]

//this code is called from anonymous namespace, in .CPP file
    SomeClassSingleton::getInstance().someF();

Visual C++ Screams an error:

> this declaration has no storage class or type specifier

This code works under GCC and C++ Builder.    I haven't worked in Visual C++ so far, so what am I doing wrong :)  ?

Thanks!
Dushan

Comment: Compiles for me in VS 2013. Which version are you using?

Comment: The same one  :)  WTF ? :D

Comment: Hmm, I just cut and pasted your post, removed the text and added a main function around the last line. Maybe try just doing that in a new project to make sure it isn't something wrong with your VS installation.

Comment: Actually it seems it   yells an error when I try to put it directly into the .cpp file (in the anonymous namespace outside of any function or anything).  I try to pull off   SingletonFactory::getInstance().registerNew(id,functionCreator)      thing

Comment: If you just put that line outside of a function, it isnt valid code. It either needs to be called inside a function (like main) or possibly as part of another declaration like 'int x = SomeClassSingleton::getInstance().someF();' By itself (outside of a function) the code looks like an incomplete declaration of a `getInstance` function.

Comment: Yeah,  bool success = FileIndexerFactory::getInstance().registerNew(MP3_INDEXER, mp3IndexerCreator);  actually changed everything :)

Comment: Thanks buddy you were right! It worked this way :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as @The Dark  said,

adding a declaration in front of the function call :

// in other words:  bool success =   :)

bool success = FileIndexerFactory::getInstance().registerNew(MP3_INDEXER, mp3IndexerCreator);

Worked :)

That's what I get from   Coding at   4:38 AM :)